# Most efficient way to notify serving machine when served has completed task (all within a local network)?

Tags: parallel-processing, local-network

I have a tentative plan to write a script that, given a large task, parallel processes the job across a local network of linux machines.

My question is, how can I best notify a computer serving up parts of the job to child computers when the child has completed its chunk of the job? My first thought was to have each child write to a known file with status updates, but that seemed inefficient. Is there a better solution?

PS: I know the question is sparse on details. This is my first time working with a lot of these concepts and just generally with anything this involved. I am definitely learning as I go, so if there's something relevant that I haven't included, please let me know and I can try to include it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to have a look at Gearman (http://gearman.org/). I hope it will fit your task as well as mine.
Basically it takes the responsibility for all the client-worker notifications.
Your task would be just to have 2 pieces:

1. the worker which will pick a piece of job from Gearman, do it's job and return result back.
2. the client which will chunk the whole job into pieces and feed it to Gearman, wait until the everything is done and "clue" results returned back by Gearman.

The Gearman is just a middle man which serves the queue of tasks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'll check it out, but for this project I would like to hand-roll my own solution, since I'm using it as a chance to learn how to handle different aspects of the network.
I really just want to know what the most efficient way of communicating progress with machines on the network and the parent would be (without using third-party products).